# Generate cloud endpoint client library update libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

On eclipse (appengine -> android) , how can i update the libraries that are generated by the command
'Generate cloud endpoint client library', so that it will then always generate the updated version ?

I mean google-api-client-1.18.0.jar to google-api-client-1.20.0.jar for example.

Where do they come from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint libraries are updated automatically each time you generate them from the backend project. If you don't see a class or a method, most probably it is due to one of the following:
1. a method is marked static and public. Make it private and manually add the @Apimethod annotation. 
2. Also, sometimes the name of the endpoint library is different from the original class name in the backend project. Pay attention to the name attribute of the @Api annotation on the class name.
You may find these links useful:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#api_api-scoped_annotations
https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/google-cloud-endpoints-for-android/
Hope this resolves ur issue

Comment: Hi Nammar, thanks for the response, but what i was wanting was to have updated libraries on endpoint-libs\libnovacoletaendpoint-v1\novacoletaendpoint\libs for example, for updating google-api-client-1.18.0.jar to google-api-client-1.20.0.jar.

Comment: Hi That seems to be done automatically. Did u try cleaning then building your backend and client projects? If not, can't you just include the jar manually?

Comment: I´ve cleaned, but the client end up with the same libraries like (google-api-client-1.18.0.jar). I can update manually the android project. But them when i generate again the client library, i have to again do this manual step. I don´t know from where the server project gets this libraries.